# Backtrace while Kernel Panic

Tags: macos, kernel, backtrace, panic

Is it possible to get backtrace of kext without attaching with gdb as described
at

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/KEXTConceptDebugger/debug_tutorial.html

if I have the panic log?

Somehow like this:

1. Get the address of kext caused panic from panic log
2. Generate dSYM file with `kextutil`
3. Paste the method's names from dSYM file into panic log to get backtrace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple's tech note tn2063 describes analysing panics in detail. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#technotes/tn2063/_index.html

In addition, tn2118 describes analyzing kernel core dumps:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2004/tn2118.html

You can get the kernel to dump on panic, then take that core dump and analyze it against the symbolicated kernel. You add your own kext's symbols to the kernel's with gdb's add-symbol-file command.

Comment: I want to read the backtrace not only with addresses but with methods names. I am developing the kext